# Standard C# class/approach for representing a cash-flow "umbrella" value?

Tags: c#

I am creating a program to model my financial ingoings and outgoings
For example, one value is "outgoings", made up of "rent" and "livingCosts",
and then "livingCosts" is made up of "food", "entertainment" and "houseBills" etc.

I want to define this "umbrella-term" relationship between the numeric values. I could create my own class, but I suspected there might already be a class / special approach in C# to do this, as it seems like a common problem. Is there?

Comment: Did you do a research to find out if there is such class? Tell us what you've found. As far as I know, .NET framework does not come with such functionality on its own.

Comment: Read the rules before you ask any questions.  There is an auto-ban designed especially for new users who cannot ask high quality questions.

Comment: Well, I did search for about an hour on google, I just did not know what key words to use in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such class for two reasons: it's trivial to create and everyone needs it to be a bit different. So actually making a class for it that then has to be customized, where the customization takes more work and code than the actual class is not very efficient.

You will have to roll your own.